# Installing Emscripten, LLVM version appears incorrect

Tags: emscripten

I'm trying to install the emscripten SDK on Linux and can't figure out the source of this error.

I've intsalled using

`./emsdk install latest`
`./emsdk activate latest`

Any call to `emcc` gives this message

> WARNING  root: LLVM version appears incorrect (seeing "version",
>   expected "3.2")
>
> INFO     root: (Emscripten: Running sanity checks)
>
> CRITICAL root: Cannot find
>   /home/lx/Documents/dev/emsdk/clang/e1.37.28_64bit/llvm-ar, check the
>   paths in ~/.emscripten

If it will help, `./emsdk list` gives

```
The following precompiled tool packages are available for download:
           clang-nightly-e1.37.28-2018_01_17_21_16-64bit
           clang-nightly-e1.37.28-2018_01_17_22_36-64bit
           clang-e1.37.1-64bit      
           clang-e1.37.27-64bit     
    (*)    clang-e1.37.28-64bit         INSTALLED
           node-4.1.1-32bit         
           node-4.1.1-64bit         
           node-8.9.1-32bit         
    (*)    node-8.9.1-64bit             INSTALLED
           emscripten-1.30.0        
           emscripten-1.34.1        
           emscripten-1.35.0        
           emscripten-1.37.1        
           emscripten-1.37.27       
    (*)    emscripten-1.37.28           INSTALLED
           emscripten-nightly-1.37.28-2018_01_17_21_16
           emscripten-nightly-1.37.28-2018_01_17_22_36

The following tools can be compiled from source:
           clang-tag-e1.37.31-32bit 
           clang-tag-e1.37.32-32bit 
           clang-tag-e1.37.31-64bit 
           clang-tag-e1.37.32-64bit 
           clang-incoming-32bit     
           clang-incoming-64bit     
           clang-master-32bit       
           clang-master-64bit       
           emscripten-tag-1.37.31-32bit
           emscripten-tag-1.37.32-32bit
           emscripten-tag-1.37.31-64bit
           emscripten-tag-1.37.32-64bit
           binaryen-tag-1.37.31-32bit
           binaryen-tag-1.37.32-32bit
           binaryen-tag-1.37.31-64bit
           binaryen-tag-1.37.32-64bit
           emscripten-incoming-32bit
           emscripten-master-32bit  
           emscripten-incoming-64bit
           emscripten-master-64bit  
           binaryen-master-32bit    
           binaryen-master-64bit    

The following precompiled SDKs are available for download: (Run "git pull" followed by "./emsdk update-tags" to pull in the latest list)
         sdk-nightly-1.37.28-2018_01_17_21_16-64bit
         sdk-nightly-1.37.28-2018_01_17_22_36-64bit
         sdk-1.37.27-64bit        
    *    sdk-1.37.28-64bit          INSTALLED

The following SDKs can be compiled from source:
         sdk-incoming-32bit       
         sdk-incoming-64bit       
         sdk-master-32bit         
         sdk-master-64bit         
         sdk-tag-1.37.31-32bit    
         sdk-tag-1.37.32-32bit    
         sdk-tag-1.37.31-64bit    
         sdk-tag-1.37.32-64bit
```

Comment: Try running "source /home/lx/Documents/dev/emsdk/emsdk_env.sh" first